# Mongodb findOneAndUpdate function is inserting new document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just need to update serviceActiveFlag status whenever i make an update api call.After an  update api call,i can see a new document with empty vehicle array is created as shown below.

```
_id:59c76073c11d3929148f500f
vehicle:Array
_v:0
```

id field will override upon every put api call.

Can some one help me to resolve this issue?

schema

```
var localTransportSchema = new Schema({

        name: { type: String, required: false, trim: true },
        contact: {
            addressLine1: { type: String, required: false },        
            serviceActiveFlag: { type: String, required: false, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },
    }, 
    vehicle: [{
        vehicleType:{ type: String, required: false, enum: ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'suv', 'mpv', 'luxury'] },        
    }]
});
module.exports.accomodationModel = mongoose.model(collection, localTransportSchema);
```

controller

```
var updates = {
            $set: {
                "contact.addressLine1": req.body['addressLine1'],                
                "contact.serviceActiveFlag": req.body['serviceActiveFlag']
            }
    };

    transportModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "name": req.body['providerName']},
        updates, { returnOriginal: false, upsert: false }, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);
                return res.status(409).json({
                    "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " in transport details table"
                });
            } else if (doc === null) {
                logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details : - unable to update database");
                return res.status(409).json({
                    "Message": "Error while updating transport details for provider " + req.body['providerName'] + " due to " + err.message
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: What version of mongoose are you using? Also what is the output of `doc` in the callback when the query completes.

Comment: I am using 4.11.11.Doc returns the updated document.

Comment: Are you sure then that there isn't some other operation adding the unwanted document? Also, [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) doesn't list `returnOriginal` as an option

Comment: Yes.No other operation is adding unwanted document

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with mongoose but could this be an issue with your exports? In your schema you are exporting `accomodationModel` but your controller is referencing `transportModel`.

Answer (score 0):

`dbModel.findOneAndUpdate()` of mongoose insert a new document only when your filter query(where claus) failed to find the existing document i.e there is no matching document exist in your collection.
So mongoose will insert the new document to the collection. This works similar to `upsert:true` of `update()`

Ref :[Official docs about findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)