# Unable to add new item to MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using the below code to update an existing document in a collection.I would like to push anew item to an array.However script neither throws exception nor add anything to array.

Requesting an experts advise to solve the issue.

```
transportModel.findOne({ "name": req.body['providerName'], "contact.postalCode": parseInt(req.body['postalCode']) },function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);                    
    } else if (doc === null) {
        logger.error("Error while updating record in transport details : - unable to update database");                   
    } else {

        doc.contact.addressLine1= req.body['addressLine1']
        doc.contact.addressLine2= req.body['addressLine2']

        //An array  in transportModel.
        //Add new items to array                  
        doc.vehicle.push({
                vehicleType:req.body['vehicleType'],                            
            })                                         
            doc.save()
    }                
});
```

Comment: Wild guess there, but isn't `.push()` async in your case ? If that is the case, maybe the `doc.save()` is executing before the actual push.

Comment: My bad.I was returning the response before saving the document.Now it's working fine

Comment: Is there any way to check if doc.save() is returning any error?

Comment: If the problem is resolved, delete this question.

Comment: @seblor what? Maybe `1 + 1` is async too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$push` method:

```
transportModel.update(
    { ...your query here }, 
    { $push: { vehicle:{ vehicleType:req.body['vehicleType'] } } },
    done
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.My controller code was correct.It's just that i placed doc.save after return statement.I have tried the same scenario using findOneandUpdate function before and it was throwing some error.It would be great if you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387861/mongodb-findoneandupdate-function-is-inserting-new-document